# Algorithm for splitting array into subarrays with sums close to the target value

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I have an array of positive integers, $A = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$.
Let $s(A)$ denote the sum of elements of array $A$.
I also have an integer $t$, such that $1 < t \le s(A)$.

I want to split the array $A$ into $m$ contiguous subarrays $(A_1, ..., A_m)$, for which I'll get a minimum of function $f$, defined as

$$
f(A_1, ..., A_m) = \sum_{1 \le i \le m}{(s(A_i) - t)^2}.
$$

Please note that I'm talking specifically about arrays, so the order of elements does matter.

Here is a simple example.

Let $t = 13$ and
$$
A = (1, 6, 7, 10, 3, 2, 10).
$$
With the following subarrays
$$
A_1 = (1, 6, 7)\\
A_2 = (10, 3) \\
A_3 = (2, 10) \\
$$
the value of $f(A_1, A_2, A_3) = (14-13)^2 + (13 - 13)^2 + (12 - 13)^2 = 2$.

I don't need an exact solution. Good heuristic would be sufficient.

Comment: Is a two-approximation good enough?  Can you think of a greedy algorithm?  How far off can _the natural_ greedy algorithm be?  Ps., this is [NP-hard even for $m=3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem).

Comment: I think factor 2 approximation should be good enough. I stumbled on this problem during development of commercial application, so I'd have to run some tests and assess the results.

Comment: It might haven't been clear before, so I specified that subarrays should be contiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it exactly using dynamic programming, though that might be too slow or might require too much memory. Calculate an array $B(\ell,k)$, which is the minimal error obtained by dividing $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ into $\ell$ parts. This can be implemented in time and space $O(mn)$ by calculating (in advance) the running sums $\sum_{i \leq t} a_i$.